# Behavior of NodeArray.insertBefore

Tags: javascript

By doing a JavaScript function to move order of HTML elements in a container id="ArticleContents", I had to face the following behavior by trying to move the order of elements in NodeArray with .insertBefore():

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
  currentItemID= event.target.id
  //... code to have articleContentSeleted=document.getElementById("DIV I want to move up or down")
  
  if (articleContentSeleted){
    childrenExistingRow=document.getElementById("ArticleContents").children;
    existingRow=document.getElementById("ArticleContents");
    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(ChildrenExistingRow, ArticleContentSeleted);


    if (currentItemID =="MoveUp" && index!=0){existingRow.insertBefore(articleContentSeleted,childrenExistingRow[index-1]);};

    if (currentItemID =="MoveDown" && index !=childrenExistingRow.length){existingRow.insertBefore(articleContentSeleted,childrenExistingRow[index+2]);};
  }
});
```

It works "almost" from the first try to make the articleContentSeleted moveUP with:

```
if (currentItemID =="MoveUp" && index!=0){existingRow.insertBefore(articleContentSeleted,childrenExistingRow[index-1]);};
```

But It requested me many time to manage to do the moveDOWN with:

```
if (currentItemID =="MoveDown" && index !=childrenExistingRow.length){existingRow.insertBefore(articleContentSeleted,childrenExistingRow[index+2]);};
```

And now I'm curious to know why

```
if (currentItemID =="MoveDown" && index !=childrenExistingRow.length){existingRow.insertBefore(articleContentSeleted,childrenExistingRow[index+1]);};
```

didn't do the job...

console.log(childExistingRow):

```
HTMLCollection(2) [textarea#Editor_Text1_0, textarea#Editor_img_1, Editor_Text1_0: textarea#Editor_Text1_0, Editor_img_1: textarea#Editor_img_1]
0: textarea#Editor_Text1_0
1: textarea#Editor_img_1
length: 2
Editor_Text1_0: textarea#Editor_Text1_0
Editor_img_1: textarea#Editor_img_1
__proto__: HTMLCollection
```

The behavior is the same if childExistingRow contains 2, 3 or 10 elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insertBefore()` itself seems to work well, using the xysibling properties you can avoid dealing with indices, lookups and the like:

```js
let cnt=0;
function up(event) {
  let node = event.target.parentNode;
  let container = node.parentNode;
  if (node.previousElementSibling)
    container.insertBefore(node, node.previousElementSibling);
  log.innerText=++cnt;
}

function down(event) {
  let node = event.target.parentNode;
  let container = node.parentNode;
  if (node.nextElementSibling)
    container.insertBefore(node, node.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling);
  log.innerText=++cnt;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="background:red">
    <button onclick="up(event)">&lt;</button>
      1
    <button onclick="down(event)">&gt;</button>
  </div>
  <div style="background:green">
    <button onclick="up(event)">&lt;</button>
      2
    <button onclick="down(event)">&gt;</button>
  </div>
  <div style="background:lightblue">
    <button onclick="up(event)">&lt;</button>
      3
    <button onclick="down(event)">&gt;</button>
  </div>
</div>
Clicks:<span id="log">0</span>
```

---

Maybe I understand your question after all:

> ```
> existingRow.insertBefore(articleContentSeleted,childrenExistingRow[index+1]);
> ```

Inserts the row before the row it follows it, back to its current place. Remember that it's not about indices, but the items.

So it's **not** 1) remove X from index x, 2) all indices shift one down, 3) insert X before the element which is at index x+1 now.

But more like 1) take item Y at position x+1, 2) remove X from index x, 3) insert X before item Y. Back to its original place.

That's why the example has `container.insertBefore(node, node.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling);`, also using that

> ***`referenceNode`***
> The node before which `newNode` is inserted. If this is `null`, then `newNode` is inserted at the end of `parentNode`'s child nodes.

(from [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore))

Comment: Thanks, it NOW it makes sense for me